# C++ on Vistual Studio with CMake error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

My CMakeLists.txt looks like following (I don't think the content of CMakeLists.txt is important since the code compiles well with CLion on Linux, but including the details should not do any harm):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(ambulance)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
if (UNIX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -pthread ")

    include_directories(ambulance builder control include include/unix io main model view)

    add_executable(ambulance
            control/Ambulance.cpp
            control/Ambulance.h
            main/main.cpp
            view/AmbulanceUI.cpp
            view/AmbulanceUI.h
            model/Doctor.cpp
            model/Doctor.h
            model/Patient.cpp
            model/Patient.h
            control/PatientAdmin.cpp
            control/PatientAdmin.h
            model/Person.cpp
            model/Person.h
            control/DoctorAdmin.cpp
            control/DoctorAdmin.h
            model/Treatment.cpp
            model/Treatment.h
            io/PeopleIO.h
            io/AmbulancePersistence.cpp
            io/AmbulancePersistence.h
            io/AmbulancePeopleIOElement.cpp
            io/AmbulancePeopleIOElement.h
            builder/PatientBuilder.cpp
            builder/PatientBuilder.h
            builder/DoctorBuilder.cpp
            builder/DoctorBuilder.h
            builder/PersonBuilder.cpp
            builder/PersonBuilder.h
            include/json_macro.h
            include/system_macro.h
            control/ScheduleAdmin.cpp
            control/ScheduleAdmin.h
            model/ScheduleElement.cpp
            model/ScheduleElement.h
            model/DailySchedule.cpp
            model/DailySchedule.h
            include/unix/Logger.h
            include/unix/Logger.cpp
            include/json.hpp
            logger/Logger.h
            logger/Logger.cpp)
else ()
    include_directories(ambulance builder control include include/win io main model view)

    add_executable(ambulance
            include/json.hpp
            control/Ambulance.cpp
            control/Ambulance.h
            main/main.cpp
            view/AmbulanceUI.cpp
            view/AmbulanceUI.h
            model/Doctor.cpp
            model/Doctor.h
            model/Patient.cpp
            model/Patient.h
            control/PatientAdmin.cpp
            control/PatientAdmin.h
            model/Person.cpp
            model/Person.h
            control/DoctorAdmin.cpp
            control/DoctorAdmin.h
            model/Treatment.cpp
            model/Treatment.h
            io/PeopleIO.h
            io/AmbulancePersistence.cpp
            io/AmbulancePersistence.h
            io/AmbulancePeopleIOElement.cpp
            io/AmbulancePeopleIOElement.h
            builder/PatientBuilder.cpp
            builder/PatientBuilder.h
            builder/DoctorBuilder.cpp
            builder/DoctorBuilder.h
            builder/PersonBuilder.cpp
            builder/PersonBuilder.h
            include/json_macro.h
            include/system_macro.h
            include/win/Logger.h
            include/win/Logger.cpp
            control/ScheduleAdmin.cpp
            control/ScheduleAdmin.h
            model/ScheduleElement.cpp
            model/ScheduleElement.h
            model/DailySchedule.cpp
            model/DailySchedule.h
            logger/Logger.cpp
            logger/Logger.h)
endif (UNIX)
```

And here is the content of CMakeSettings.txt

```
{
"configurations": [
{
"name": "x64-Release",
"generator": "Ninja",
"configurationType": "RelWithDebInfo",
"inheritEnvironments": [
"msvc_x64_x64"
],
"buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\CMakeBuilds\${workspaceHash}\build\${name}",
"installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\CMakeBuilds\${workspaceHash}\install\${name}",
"cmakeCommandArgs": "",
"buildCommandArgs": "-v",
"ctestCommandArgs": ""
}
]
}
```

I made the code primarily on Linux and compile in a virtual Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio Enterprise. The building was still successful yesterday, but since today every time I try to compile it, I have a endless loop that says:

> [0/1] "...cmake.exe" ".../x64-Release"
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: ...

Finally the error Description says:

> manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

What could be a solution to this? Must I reinstall visual studio (What is incredible uncomfortable since my virtual machine is incredible slow).

Thank you

Comment: Hmm, there are 2 proper steps: 1) Provide output of `cmake .. --trace` and `cmake .. --trace-expand` 2) Fill an issue on https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues. EDIT: filling the issue may be too fast yet, just share the logs :) And what command do you use to configure project?

Comment: Hi, I added the content of CMakeSettings.txt if that is what you mean with "command do you use to configure project". The text generated by Visual Studio though.

Comment: Ok, CMake support for Visual Studio is kinda experimental and it seems it is more like VS issue. I'd suggest invoking CMake manually on your source directory and using generated Visual Studio project instead of direct CMake.

Comment: That is also what I thought. Thank you :)

Comment: Here https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1120 they suggest that something is wrong with timestamps of your files (sources or headers).

Comment: Hint about the CMake code: You have two `add_executable` for Windows and Linux, where most of source files are the same. For avoid the duplication, you may collect common source files into the variable (say, `COMMON_SOURCES`) and use that variable in the `add_executable` calls. Alternatively, you may have `SPECIAL_SOURCES` variable and fill it conditionally with source files, specific for Window or Linux; then use **single** `add_executable()` which enumerates common sources plus `SPECIAL_SOURCES` variable.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you figure out how to fix it? I have cmake 3.12.18081601-MSVC_2 and ninja 1.8.2, both installed through Visual Studio. It happens both when running the build from Visual Studio, and also when running cmake and then ninja manually from the visual studio command line. Note that the cmake loop doesn't happen when initially calling cmake, but when calling ninja. It's ninja that calls cmake over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same issue. In my case, running a tool that recursively sets all file timestamps on the source folder (source, **not** build folder) helped. I assume some tool updated one of the source files to a time in the future and that made cmake think it has to regenerate because the source file is newer than the build file. Maybe this helps you as well?

This is the tool I used: http://web.archive.org/web/20101226014112/www.touchdotexe.com/

Just use it on the command line:

```
touch.exe -R C:/my/source/folder
```