# ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, clion, qt6

I'm getting the following output when trying to run my Qt project:

```
Desktop_Qt_6_5_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug 
[0/1 ?/sec] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/UsuÃ¡rio/Documents/QT/MapGeneratorUI/build-MapGeneratorUI- Desktop_Qt_6_5_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug
ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

17:47:09: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project MapGeneratorUI (kit: Desktop Qt 6.5.0 MinGW 64-bit) When executing step "Build"
17:47:09: Elapsed time: 04:54.
```

- Qt version: 6.5
- CMake version: 3.24.2
- System: Windows 10

I tried:

- Reinstalling Qt.
- Deleting the build folder.
- Synchronizing the system time.
- The solution mentioned this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360538/17726418)
- I also did all this in a brand new project.

but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the path of your project.

Your username (`UsuÃ¡rio`) seem to cause that problem, although this seems to be an issue with just **CLion**, as far as I know, see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/zcku06/problems_with_using_clion/) for more information.

I have tested this using **Qt Creator**, and was unable to reproduce the error.

To fix this problem, you could simply use a path that does not contain that type of characters.