# Clion issue when editing Cmake

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I'm experiencing the following issue with Clion for Windows (I'm new to it).
I have a C project in which the only file is `main.c`. If I edit the `CMakelists.txt`, whatever the change, and I hit run, the building fails, returning the error
`ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries` 
If I undo the changes in the CMake file, it still gives the same error. Whatever I do, the building keeps failing.

What am I missing?

I tried reloading the CMake and deleting the `cmake-build-debug` folder. Nothing seems to work. The only way to make it run again is creating a new project.

EDIT
I think I've found an issue
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYyRL.png)

The entry I highlighted in red sets to that value by default. I tried changing it to the project folder and it worked. Then Clion changed it again to that, but right now is working. I think the issue is related to something like that.

Comment: Does your source directory has some special symbols in it, like in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76129720/ninja-error-manifest-build-ninja-still-dirty-after-100-tries)?

Comment: No, it's this one "G:/Il mio Drive/CLionProjects/latent/.idea/latente/cmake-build-debug"

Comment: Please, add to your question **full output** of the build process, not just the final line. Like in the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76129720/ninja-error-manifest-build-ninja-still-dirty-after-100-tries).